# How do I set up a Mail.app rule for removing attachments?

Tags: mail.app, attachments, mail-rules

While Mail.app offers a menu item for removing attachments from e-mail, I find myself wanting to make a rule for removing attachments from e-mails. Anyone knows how that can be done? AppleScript, perhaps?

So basically, a Mail.app rule that works like this:

1. If sender is suchandsuch and attachment type is executable (this is already possible).
2. Remove attachments from e-mail

Comment: In Apple Script, attachments can apparently only be saved but not deleted.

Answer (score -2):

I just made a [screencast](http://cl.ly/1t1R1i3C123V) how to do this (however, you have to delete the message in order to remove the executable):

[image]

Comment: Your rule moves any mail with an executable attached into a specific mailbox. This isn't exactly what the question was asking for...

Comment: Yeah, deleting the e-mail kinda defeats the purpose – I just want to get rid of the attachment :)